# Libgdx - Desktop - Mouse hovering over a 3D Model Instance

Tags: 3d, libgdx, intersection

I am trying to calculate when the mouse is hovering over a 3D Model Instance in Libgdx. As of right now, all my model instances are perfect rectangles. I have created a pick ray from the mouse x and y coordinates and used the Intersection class to try and calculate an intersection, but it it seems that the intersection only registers when the mouse is in an area of the model instances bounding box located at the center of the screen. When in actuality, the model instance is located somewhat off to the side.

My theory is that the bounding box only stores dimension, and not location, of the model instance. But I have yet to prove this, is there another way to calculate an intersection from a ray made from the mouse coordinates and a model instance's bounding box?

Here is my current code.

```
// This class is correctly registered as an input processor
public boolean mouseMoved(int x, int y) {
    // Get the ray from the mouse's location
    Ray ray = pCam.getPickRay(x, y);

    // Get the model's bounding box
    BoundingBox box = new BoundingBox();
    box2.calculateBoundingBox(box);

    /* Partial 'box2' initialization code
        mb.node().id = "box2";
        mb.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN))).box(4f, 1f, 4f);
        box2 = new ModelInstance(model, "box2");
        box2.transform.setToTranslation(2, 0, -2); 
     */

    // If the ray resides in the bounding box
    if (Intersector.intersectRayBoundsFast(ray, box)) {
        // Change the model instance color to red
        box2.materials.get(0).set(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED));
    }
    // Otherwise
    else {
        // Set the model instance color back to green
        box2.materials.get(0).set(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN));
    }
    // Default return false
    return false;
}
```

If you can offer any suggestions or code that can help me out, I would be eternally grateful. Also, let me know if I can add anything to clarify or help you as you assist me.

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.xoppa.com/interacting-with-3d-objects/

Comment: I've read over this and I still don't see what I'm doing differently that would provide the error that I am seeing. Could you offer any suggestion as to how I may edit my code to match that of the articles?

Comment: No, your code is too different (e.g. calculating the bounding box on every mouse move isn't a good idea since it's a very expensive method). Perhaps you can edit the code of the tutorial to match your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

The method `Intersector.intersectRayBoundsFast` returns the ***intersection relative to the ray's origin***. You simply need to add the ray's origin to get the point of intersection